# Apache is not returning 404 error for non existing URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, error-handling, http-status-code-404

**here is what I want**

if someone entered a link that does not exist ,then it should throw 404 Error page of webhost,But currently it is returning 200.

> `www.example.com/wrong_page.php` --> this should throw an error 404 but
>   is is throwing 200 right now.I SEE SAME PAGE AS 
>   `www.example.com/index.php`

What might have gone wrong ? is there any configuration that is needed to be done in the `htaccess.php` ? please help

Comment: What do you mean by "throwing 200"? Http status 200 indicates a success, sure, but usually that means you get an actual reply, some payload. So what _do_ you get?

Comment: You should check your http servers access and error log files to gain more information. Also posting the relevant bits of your configuration would make sense.

Comment: yes it shows success page. I see same  www.example.com/index.php page also for  www.example.com/wrong.php

Comment: I will try to get some configuration detail and post

Comment: And what does that "success page" actually show? Because apache has no such page builtin. So it must be your own setup that you see.

Comment: I see the same page  www.example.com/index.php

Comment: I ask about the content, not about the URL.

Comment: Check your `.htaccess`.

Comment: @AnkitSingh : WHAT SHOULD I CHECK ? Can you suggest something

Comment: What is your virtual host configuration?

Comment: Look for this line `ErrorDocument 404 /any_file_name.php`.

Comment: You have some redirection rule in effect, that is all. Please start reading the documentation of the tools you use and go through a few "getting started tutorials". This is not rocket science, but you need to learn a few things to get going.

Comment: I was working on old existing project. Someone earlier had written `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]` in .htaccess file. Please some one post good answer with rewrite rule so that i can accept your answer and close this question!!! Thanks

Comment: @arkascha : you were right !!! it was because of redirection rule. Could you please add your answer so that I can accept. Thank you so much

Comment: @Hitesh Sure, did that, just as you asked.

Comment: @arkascha - accepted ur answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have some already existing rewriting rule in effect, that is all.

Something that redirects all requests to `/index.php` which actually is a quite common thing in web applications. Such index script acts as a router, processing *all* requests. This serves as a central entry point and simplifies to define the structure of the implemented engine.

So you should look for already existing internal rewriting rules inside the http servers host configuration or in some dynamic configuration file (".htaccess").

Answer (score 0):

let php send the header 404: (in wrong.php)

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
```

re-reading your question: is wrong_page.php your error page, or just your example of the non exsiting page?

If so: do you have a custom error page on you site? Then place this headerline in that file

edit: (question was changed)

So the index.php is still loading. 
Is no 404 template for seen?

Comment: What a recommendation. Without any attempt to find out what is actually going on you simply tell the OP to overwrite the symptom. _Shaking my head_...

Comment: when reading the question as "the 404 template page wrong_page.php is returning 200" the answer makes sense, I think. But since editing the question, it is clear that was not what TS meant

Answer (score -1):

maybe there is some page that actually exists at that location. Otherwise that would never be the case